# mySQL select columns from different tables

Tags: mysql, select, union

1000 Apologies if I've repeated a question, couldn't find an answer here to my question.

I'm try to retrieve the data from 2 separate columns from 2 unrelated tables in the same query.

I've tried using a `UNION` statement, but the problem is that I need to be able to separate the results into 'venues' and 'programmes' - here was what I did:

```
SELECT venue_name
FROM my_venues
UNION
SELECT programme_title
FROM my_programmes;
```

Maybe it's not necessary to combine the query and I can just do 2 separate queries? The database won't be especially large, but it seems unnecessary...

Help and thanks!

Comment: What an odd thing to say. This is a site where you ask people for help isn't it?! This is not a helpful comment.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a constant column in both selects, with the same name, but different values:

```
SELECT "venues"  as source, venue_name as thing_name
FROM my_venues
UNION ALL
SELECT "programmes"  as source, programme_title as thing_name
FROM my_programmes;
```

Now:

- Rows with value "venues" for column
  `source` will come from the table
  `my_venues` ,
- rows with value "programmes" for
  column `source` will come from table
  `my_programmes`.

Comment: Good catch on the `UNION ALL`, indeed, there will be no more duplicate rows, so checking can and should be avoided.

Comment: Hmm. The query returns the results ok, but all the returned results have the same key `venue_name`. The query is valid, but the line `SELECT "programmes"  as source, programme_title` is being ignored and the `programme_titles` are all given a key of `venue_name`

Comment: I'm sorry, UNION needs to have identical tables. That includes both column names - rename the second column (for example to `thing_name`) as well.

Comment: Same result I'm afraid.. `Array( [source] => venues [venue] => some venue)` and for the `programme_titles` : `Array( [source] => programmes [venue] => some programme`.